# Java NoClassDefFoundError occurring even when the class path is added

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile and run the `PercolationVisualizer` in https://github.com/samet/Coursera-Algorithms-I-Assignment-1. According to http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/, the required dependencies `StdDraw.java` and `In.java` should be present in the `stdlib` package.

After cloning the repository, I copied [stdlib.jar](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/stdlib.jar) to the `src` directory and then compiled PercolationVisualizer using the following command:

```
javac -cp .:stdlib.jar PercolationVisualizer.java
```

(I did the same for `Percolation.java`). However, when I try to run the program using `java PercolationVisualizer`, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: In
    at PercolationVisualizer.main(PercolationVisualizer.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: In
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

I don't understand the `NoClassDefFoundError` for `In`, since it should be included in `stdlib`. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Try to open the jar and check if the class is really present on it, and if present check that the package is the same that you used.

Comment: `java -cp .:stdlib.jar PercolationVisualizer`

Comment: @[Davide](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1803853/davide-lorenzo-marino): I opened the jar using `jar xf stdlib.jar`, and there is indeed an `In.java` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Windows, use the semicolon as CLASSPATH separator ..

```
javac -cp ".;stdlib.jar" PercolationVisualizer.java Percolation.java WeightedQuickUnionUF.java PercolationStats.java
```

If you are on linux/*nix, use the colon as CLASSPATH separator ...

```
javac -cp ".:stdlib.jar" PercolationVisualizer.java Percolation.java WeightedQuickUnionUF.java PercolationStats.java
```

For more information look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

If you want to debug the process of compilation, use the "-verbose" flag. It will display you CLASSPATH, the "lodaing **jar_file** ..." statements. If it has not recognized your jar file, it will now show the "loading" statement.

Comment: I'm on Linux, so the colon would be correct in this case.

Comment: @KurtPeek, I just downloaded your code and compiled. It compiled for me on windows using the semicolon syntax.

Comment: @KurtPeek, If it still doesn't work, you can try to put the class path in the CLASSPATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I finally unjar'd stdlib.jar into the working directory, after which the compilation worked. (This is indeed the first method to use stdlib described in http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/).

Comment: Creative! Ok. You can try alternatives later, as the need arises.